# If $r > r' >0$ then $cl(B(x,r')) \subseteq B(x,r)$

Tags: general-topology

Given $(E,d)$ a metric space and $r > r' >0$. I'd like to see that  $cl(B(x,r')) \subseteq B(x,r)$.

I was trying to prove that given $y \in cl(B(x,r')) \Rightarrow y \in B(x,r)$.

If $y \in cl(B(x,r')) \Rightarrow \forall \ \epsilon > 0: B(y,\epsilon) \ \cap \ B(x,r') \neq \emptyset$. How can I prove that $d(x,y) < r$, i.e $y \in B(x,r)$?

Comment: Let $y \in \overline{B(x, r')}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists $p \in B(x, r')$ s.t $d(y,p) < \epsilon$. Now $d(y,x) \leq d(y,p) + d(x,p) < r'+ \epsilon \leq r' < r$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an issue with characterization of elements of the closure, it should be: If $y \in cl(S)$ then for *every* $\epsilon>0$ one has $B(y,\epsilon) \cap S \neq \varnothing$.

**Hint:** Let $y \in cl(B(x,r'))$ and $\epsilon>0$. So $B(y,\epsilon) \cap B(x,r') \neq \varnothing$, there is some point $\alpha$ in both open balls. I.e $d(y,\alpha) < \epsilon$ and $d(x,\alpha)<r'$. In a metric space we also have the triangle inequality $d(x,y) \leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$.

Comment: You are right, I fixed the issue with the characterization of $\epsilon$.